# Django not connecting to PlanetScale , SSL error

Tags: django

Trying to use planetscale for my db platform for a Django app that i am building. However i'm running into some errors

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, "SSL connection error: no valid certificates were found, CAFile='*************', CAPath=''. One or more of the parameters passed to the function was invalid. Error 2148074333/0x8009035D")

The configuration was copied straight from planetscale

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': env('DB_NAME'),
    'HOST': env('DB_HOST'),
    'PORT': env('DB_PORT'),
    'USER': env('DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'OPTIONS': {'ssl': {'ca': env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA')}}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working.
the value for the OPTIONS key should be {'ssl': {'**ssl-ca**': env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA')}}